# Is the Doppler effect for light symmetric?

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

This is a trick question but it leads up to the real question. Let me explain.

The Doppler effect for sound is not symmetric. For a given relative velocity between source and receiver, the measured Doppler shift is different depending upon whether it is the source that is moving, or the receiver. This can be seen from the formula $$f_r = \frac{1-v_r/c}{1-v_s/c} f_s$$

$f_r$ = frequency at receiver

$f_s$ = frequency at source

$v_r$ and $v_s$ = velocities of receiver and of source, respectively, relative to the air, positive if in the direction of the propagating signal.

If the source is stationary this reduces to $f_r = (1+v/c)  f_s$, while if the receiver is stationary it reduces to $f_r = 1/(1-v/c)  f_s$.  $v$ is now simply the relative velocity between source and receiver. These are not the same (in fact the difference is equal to $v^2/c^2$). But if this was true for light we could measure the relative velocity, measure the Doppler shift and calculate the absolute velocity, violating special relativity.

Many texts simply state that the Doppler effect for light is symmetric. But this begs the question - 'is the measured Doppler effect for light equal to $1+v/c$ or $1/(1-v/c)$?' This is the main question. A subsidiary question is -'has the magnitude of the Doppler effect for light ever been experimentally measured?'

The measurement for light would be difficult but in fact very tiny frequency shifts can be measured by a procedure known as heterodyning, measuring the beat frequency between two signals with a tiny frequency difference. It might be thought the experiment could be simplified by bouncing a signal of a moving body and measuring the frequency shift back at the source, now doubling as a receiver. But unfortunately, reality is not on the side of the experimenter. The reflected Doppler effect is more nearly symmetric, even for sound. The measured shift in frequency is now the same whether it is the source/receiver or the reflecting body that is moving. But not totally symmetric. In the case of sound, the measured shift does change slightly whether you ascribe all of the relative velocity to either the source or the reflecting body, or whether you ascribe 50% of the velocity to each. But now the measured difference in Doppler shift is extremely tiny.

So the main question is 'has the magnitude of the Doppler effect ever been experimentally measured for light, and, if so, which of the two formulae, if either, does it conform to?'

Please answer the main question, and its rider, but if any of the assumptions are wrong, please explain why.

Comment: *is the measured Doppler effect for light equal to 1+v/c or 1/(1-v/c)?* Neither. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect).

Comment: Are you aware of [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect)? Note that both of your formulae are nonrelativistic approximations.

Comment: Good luck with your arguments when you are caught speeding with a https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_speed_gun

Comment: @ProfRob I learned this when I spent 20 years in space radar: Doppler guns don't measure the velocity induced doppler shift of the carrier frequency. rather they measure the change of phase (of an  IF mixed-down coherent signal) at different positions (using pulses or coded CW), so you could take pulse on a stationary car, move it and stop, another pulse, etc...and you'd get the same result: $280 and points.  on the license.  This is the origin of "Doppler Ambiguity", which I did not understand at first, since a carrier doesn't have that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not symmetric" but the equation $f_{r}=\frac{1-v_{r}/c}{1-v_{s}/c}f_{s}$ can be rewritten as, for example, $\frac{f_{r}}{1-v_{r}/c} = \frac{f_{s}}{1-v_{s}/c}$, which I would definitely call a "symmetric" formula. The major difference is that you can go to and past Mach 1, while the "Mach number" for light is always less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I like the theory part of this question: the form of the Doppler shift tells you a lot about the medium in which the waves propagate. Tl;dr: if it's asymmetric, there is an absolute rest frame, if not: special relativity.

Note that a lone sound wave has a frequency, the frequency at which the medium is vibrating; a photon does not. It's just in space, and all observers say it is moving $c$, but none agree on its frequency (and wave vector, to be precise).

The two shifts are:

$$ f_{\pm} = \sqrt{\frac{1\pm\beta}{1\mp\beta}}$$

And of course it's been measured in zillions of ways.

The Bondi $k$-Calculus, due to Bondi, derives what the doppler shift must be based on the symmetry of spacetime  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondi_k-calculus).

Meanwhile, an analysis (due to the author) derives it from the requirement that an emitted (absorbed) photon must impart a four-momentum transfer that is perpendicular to the 4-velocity of the emitter (absorber), or else they would go "off-shell", which is cute, because it automatically includes recoil in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The classical equations
$f_r = (1+v_r/c)  f_s$ and $f_r = 1/(1-v_s/c)  f_s$

have relativistic analogues that include the associated time-dilation factor:

$\displaystyle f_r = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_r^2/c^2}}\right)(1+v_r/c)  f_s
=\sqrt{\frac{1+v_r/c}{1-v_r/c}}f_s
$
and
$\displaystyle f_r = \frac{1/(1-v_s/c)}{
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_s^2/c^2}}\right)}  f_s
=\sqrt{\frac{1+v_s/c}{1-v_s/c}}f_s
$,
which are special cases of the relativistic analogue of the general case
$f_r = \frac{1+v_r/c}{1-v_s/c} f_s$

where the scaling factor (the Doppler factor) involves the relative-velocity.

Comment: How can two equations which are clearly different, reduce to the same equation?

Answer (score -1):

The Doppler effect for light is $f_E=f_S\sqrt{\frac{c+\Delta v}{c-\Delta v}}$ and of cause one can measure it.

Comment: Yes I have seen this, and the derivation specifically assumes that the non-relativistic component is 1 + v/c which implies the source is stationary.

Comment: What do E and S mean? The obvious choices of Emitter and Source don’t make sense since those are the same.

Comment: sorry, the E comes from german , "Empfänger" which means recipient , or observer.